# How to use QueryOver with nHibernate in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, c#-to-vb.net

I've been learning how to use nHibernate with Vb.net using all the examples online(which are in C#) to learn. Which has been fine for the basics, but now I'm trying to learn how to use QueryOver's JoinAlias, and going from C# to VB.net is difficult. I've been using [this page's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462004/nhibernate-queryover-select-entity-and-aggregates) as a reference, but I'm still having trouble converting an example like that to Vb.net. Could someone help me?

Comment: Which version of VB.NET are you using? Before .NET 4, VB didn't have the same lambda support as C#. If you're using an older version, that might explain some of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

the easy way would be to introduce a collection of TableResultDetailsClass in TableResultClass and use that.

```
results = session.QueryOver(Of TableResultClass)() _
    .Where(Function(tr) tr.Id = wantedId) _
    .Select(Function(tr) New With { tr.Id, tr.Details.Sum(Function(trd) trd.Property) }) _
    .List()
```

otherwise you get object[] back

```
results = session.QueryOver(Of TableResultDetailsClass)() _
    .Where(Function(td) tD.Parent.Id = wantedId) _
    .Select(Projections.Property(Function(td) tD.Parent.Id), Projections.Sum(Function(td) tD.Prpoerty)) _
    .List()
```

Original:

all you need is generics and lambdas in vb.net

```
Dim child as Child
results = session.QueryOver(Of User)()
    .Where(Function(u) u.Name = "blub")
    .JoinAlias(Function(u) u.Childs, Function child)
    .List()
```

Update: it seems you are looking for mappings. With FluentNHibernate it would look like

```
Public Class TableEntityMap Inherits ClassMap(Of TableEntity)

    Sub New()
        Id(Function(x) x.Id, "DID")

        HasMany(Of TableEntity)(Function(x) x.Details).Inverse()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TableEntityMap Inherits ClassMap(Of TableEntity)

    Sub New()
        Id(Function(x) x.Id)

        References(Of DetailsTableEntity)(Function(x) x.Parent, "Parent")

    End Sub
End Class

Dim entity as TableEntity = sess.Get(Of TableEntity)(someid)

'' get all details of this entity
Dim details = entity.Details
```

Comment: That's a pretty general, vague answer you have there... maybe I didn't specify enough?

I'm trying to aggregate 2 different tables..

Comment: sorry was a fast shot. Maybe it is best to show a queryover you want to convert or describe what you want back from a defined schema

Comment: Okay. In this case, I have Table, and DetailsTable classes. The table has a DID, but the DetailsTable has a column that's Parent, so Table. So I'm trying to join on when DetailsTable = Table. How would I do that? And I hope that helps clarify my question.

Comment: I don't think I'm looking for mappings. I'm looking for an aggregation. Err. Maybe I'll explain in more detail what I have.

Comment: I have 2 tables, TableResults and TableResultsDetails. Both of them have DIDs as correlation to the correct TableResults with TableResults details. Now, looking in the project, I found out that we have two classes that are used to represent the tables. TableResultClass and TableResultDetailsClass. TableResultClass has a DID property, but TableResultDetailsClass doesn't have a DID property, but instead it has a Parent property, which has a reference to it's respective TableResultClass.

Comment: Now, using nHibernate, which would be the best way to do a join QueryOver based on their DIDs, or, in this case, the Parent property?